# Configuring a custom magento session model

Tags: magento, session

I know that I can create a custom session in magento to store data local to my module in the session files without affecting the global namespace. To do this i simply create a model that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract` but **how do I configure it?** Is it the same as a normal model config? Does it need its own resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to initialize it within the `__construct()` method, like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->init('namespace', 'optional_session_name');
}
```